# 'Mom to 2 Yorkies' is that sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, american-english, spoken-english, informal-language, indian-english

I have seen people writing on social media like 'Mom to 2 Yorkies' (mostly for pet animals). Is that usage grammatically correct?

My question is about 'to'. What is the difference between Mom of 2 Yorkies and Mom to 2 Yorkies? Are both have the same meaning?

Comment: It's not a sentence. But it's fine in very informal contexts like social media profiles (some style guides will tell you to write "two", and to write in complete sentences, if you're being more formal). Why do you have a problem with it? (Apart from the obvious, a human being a mother of dogs.)

Comment: It is **grammatically** correct. It is **metaphorically** correct. It is **"questionable"** whether it is **factually** correct or it is **logically** correct !

Comment: I know someone who might be described in an SMS as 'mom to 2 Bengals'. I quite envy her.

Comment: @StuartF - 'a human being a mother of dogs' - I know plenty of guys who might be described as 'sons of dogs'. I gather that these days we may not use the correct word for a female dog, which considerably irritates my sister who breeds Springer spaniels. She has refused to sell to someone because they got funny with her when she said 'bitch'.

Comment: [She is a] Mom to 2 Yorkies. It's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular context, being a mother *of* someone, and being a mother *to* them can be quite different.

For example, you might say of a step-parent, foster parent or anyone else that has raised you that they are 'like a mother *to* you'.

That's not to say that step-parents or similar cannot legimitely say that they are a parent 'of' their step-children - you'll find that people make their own rules of language on a case-by-case basis there. But 'Yorkies', as hopefully you know, are dogs. Their 'parent' (or 'pawrent' as I'm hearing more and more) definitely didn't give birth to them, but she can be a mother *to* them.

Comment: 'pawrent' - oh dear.

Comment: I think, as a BrE speaker, that 'mother to' and 'mother of' can both apply in the case of natural birth, I think the distinction might be that 'to' discusses role, and 'of' is a matter of biology. _Lauren Conrad recently opened up about struggles she's faced since becoming a mother to two boys._ [Daily Mail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-10780455/Lauren-Conrad-gets-candid-challenging-motherhood-journey-two-sons-lost-myself.html) 4 May 2022. She is discussing the changes in her life following birth of her second child.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes. You're covering the same ground as me but from a different angle. Of course, wherever there is a step-parent or similar there is always a biological parent. As I said in my answer, a step-parent may decide to say they are both. A biological mother who raises their own children is of course both by default, but then arguably one that does *not* raise them may not be a mother *to* them.

Comment: Yes, of course you could say 'I was mother to those two boys after my brother's wife left him/died/went crazy'. But 'Marie de Guise was [natural] mother to and regent for Mary Queen of Scots', and there is a book about a nun who was 'mother to the orphans of Hunduras'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Ho hum, once again, there is not BriE, AmE or NAE difference here at all.

Comment: @Lambie - back in July, I was just covering my butt in case someone from either side of the Atlantic says 'we don't say that'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Hey, BrEng speakers don't say 'butt'!